# Pull up view in iPhone like a notification bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to implement a pull up view like that of notification bar in iPhone. the difference is it will be from bottom to top. How can I implement that?

I have enclosed the images for that:

[image]

[image: collapsed and expanded view]

Comment: NO action sheet is some thing different i want to drag from the button in upwards direction

Answer (score 0):

In that situation you will have to use the GestureRecognizer. You should use the tap when the user tab on the top left image when notification image is close or swipe gesture direction up.

Maybe this will help you to start: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_4_Gesture_Recognition_Tutorial_(Xcode_4)